# noWrap option on tilelayer is only partially working

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

To prevent multiple duplicated world maps on highest zoom level I'm using `noWrap=true` option. It's working well but only on the left side on the map (the grey area), the right side still displays extra tiles.
Why is that?

UPDATE1: Looks like it's an issue with specific Mapbox tiles or the way they are loaded?
Here noWrap and `https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/ebrelsford.ho06j5h0/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

works perfectly: [NoWrap works JSBIN link](http://jsbin.com/cokirih/1/edit?html,js,output)

But once I change to another way of loading tiles using styles

[NoWrap broken JSBIN Link](http://jsbin.com/gifival/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

I can scroll right and still get tiles

I opened a github issue, I suspect it's a bug with the library
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5938

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an issue with certain Mapbox styles and an "incomplete" usage of [`noWrap`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer-nowrap) option in your code: (emphasis mine)

> `noWrap`: Whether the layer is wrapped around the antimeridian. If `true`, the GridLayer will only be displayed once at low zoom levels. Has no effect when the map CRS doesn't wrap around. **Can be used in combination with `bounds` to prevent requesting tiles outside the CRS limits.**

- `noWrap`, as its name says, tells Leaflet not to copy the "main" world. Therefore, Leaflet has to assume that the "main" world is "infinite", and it tries to load tiles everywhere, extending the quadtree scheme: alongside tile 0/0/0 (at zoom 0), it tries to load tiles 0/1/0, 0/-1/0, etc.
- For some reason, some Mapbox styles return an image for tiles outside the normal quadtree scheme: besides tile 0/0/0, you can also get an image for 0/1/0, 0/2/0, etc. In your case, those "imaginary" tiles are always the same graphics, repeating the world. Therefore it looks like Leaflet still wraps the tiles, whereas in fact it displays different images; it is Mapbox tile server that serves the same graphics in all these images.

[image: images added by Tile Server but repeating graphics from Mapbox]

If you want to tell Leaflet not to extend the quadtree scheme, you should specify that there are no tiles available outside the "main" world.

The solution is therefore simply to use the Tile Layer [`bounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer-bounds) option in conjunction with the `noWrap` one:

```js
L.tileLayer(urlTemplate, {
  noWrap: true,
  bounds: [
    [-90, -180],
    [90, 180]
  ]
}).addTo(map);
```

Updated JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/nokasukozo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for a such detailed answer! Work like a charm. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Credit to ghybs's answer, however you can set **maxBounds** in your Map layer instead of the TileLayer. Also, **noWrap** is not required on the TileLayer anymore. Simply apply `maxBounds=[-90, -180],[90, 180]]` to your Map layer and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case of GridLayer usage:

```
    var tiles = new L.GridLayer({
        noWrap: true,
        bounds: [
            [-90, -180],
            [90, 180]
        ]
    });

    tiles.createTile = function (coords) {
        var canvas = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
        var image = new Image();
        ...
        return canvas;
    }

    tiles.addTo(map)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could be more descriptive in your answer