# noWrap = true causing artifact in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

[image: noWrap = false] 
When I have noWrap set to false when generating my tileLayer, the map looks fine but repeats on the edges.
I want to only have one map, and have the rest be the same color as the background of my website. I found that to limit the map to only one, you should set noWrap to true :

```
            var layer = new L.tileLayer(myMap, {
               noWrap: true
            });
```

However, this only works on the left hand side as seen in my image [image: noWrap = true]. The left hand side works as intended but the right hand side seems to have this weird artifact as it seems like it is trying to mirror again. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance. I am using leaflet 1.7.1

Comment: Hard to say exactly without a [mcve], but seems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477956/nowrap-option-on-tilelayer-is-only-partially-working/47482145#47482145